# Basic limit/upper bound Analysis question.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What's the proper way to prove this? Is there a direct proof? I don't want to use contradiction.

Let $f$ be bounded above by some $L \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x) \leq L$$

when the limit exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = c$. We wish to show that $c \leq L$.

Without loss of generality assume that $c, L > 0$. By definition, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0\mid |x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - c| < \epsilon$.

Then,
$$ c \leq |c - f(x)| + |f(x)| < \epsilon + L
$$
Since that holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, we have $c \leq L$.

Comment: But your proof just pushes the contradiction deeper. In your last step, to get from $c < L + ε$ for every $ε > 0$ to $c \le L$ you need contradiction (I think).

Comment: @user21820 $c \leq \inf_{\epsilon > 0} L + \epsilon = \lim_{\epsilon \searrow 0} L + \epsilon = L$

Comment: That's just pushing it even deeper!! You cannot prove the first inequality without contradiction.

Comment: Of course, you might argue that you can just add enough axioms into your axiomatization of the real numbers, so that no contradiction is needed in your proof, but that's not what we're looking for.